# Пустые скобки в ответ на $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax

Делаю запрос:

```
$.get('https://zor.uz/offer/19796022/', function(data){
console.log(data);
})
```

возвращает просто "[]", а нужен исходный код страницы

Естественно, действую в пределах одного домена (zor.uz)

Comment: А что ожидаете? Сервер вам возвращает пустой массив.

Comment: Почему он не возвращает исходный код страницы, как обычно?

Comment: а почему он должен возвращать исходный код страницы?

Comment: Потому что в data, по умолчанию, должен содержаться код страницы. Везде такой код работает, на всех площадках, с которыми работаем и на которых нужно прогрузить содержимое других страниц. Зайдите, к примеру, на olx.ua и прогрузите таким образом любую страницу

Comment: В данном случае все зависит от настроек сервера

Comment: Понимаю. Поэтому и спрашиваю, как получить исходный код страницы таким образом

Comment: Судя по всему сервер видит, что это ajax запрос, и пытается отдать какой-то json. Если воспользоваться [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) а не методом из jquery - ответ будет html

Comment: _как получить исходный код страницы таким образом_ - настроить сервер :-)

Comment: Откройте консоль в chrome, перейдите на вкладку Network. выполните этот $.get, в вкладке будет виден ваш запрос со всеми заголовками и точный ответ сервера.

Comment: Ответ сервера так и есть — []

Comment: Ну вот, поэтому вы их и видите. Сервер опознает что это ajax запрос и возвращает то, что возвращает. А что бы выяснить почему, нужно смотреть код сервера

Comment: @Mike, мне кажется я 5 комментариями выше то же самое писал :)

Comment: Ок, сделаю через fetch, спасибо

Comment: _А что бы выяснить почему_ - очевидно из-за заголовка `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` который может автоматом добавлять jquery